# Is there a C# control that lets you create a grid that's sortable like Excel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using 2010 Express and I have an array arrStudents, where each element contains the students' names (arrStudents(0).Name) and ages (arrStudents(0).Age).  I would like to present the contents of my array so that the user can see it in a 2 column by 100 row grid, like in Excel, where the Names are displayed in Column A and Ages displayed on Column B.

Then, the user can double click somewhere so that it sorts Column A alphabetically, or sorts B by ascending age.  Then, if you double click again it does the reverse and sorts column A alphabetically by descending order and column B by age in descending order.  What's the best way to come as close to this as possible in C#?

Comment: I saw DataGridView but then realized it's for SQL databases.  I think I'd like a similar control that I could populate with the contents of my array.

Comment: DataGridView isn't just for database queries.  You can populate it with the contents of your array.

Comment: You can bind a DataGridView to a collection. Here is an example: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection

Comment: Thank you for this link.  It was extremely helpful and I managed to do exactly what I wanted!  If you submit this as an answer I will select yours since you were the first one with a really helpful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the`sort` method of the `DataGridView`. You pass it which column to sort by, and either ascending or descending order.

To bind data to the `DataGridView`, you set the datasource of the control to your array:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myArray;
```

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z.aspx) shows how to sort the `DataGridView` once it is bound to your data source.